# SwitchCompat RTL support

Tags: android, switchcompat

Seems like selector file for `track` attribute is not working properly for RTL.

LTR `track` and `thumb`.

[image] [image]

RTL `track` and `thumb`. Here `thumb` is changed properly, but `track` images are still unchanged as it should display map icon on the right.

[image]

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:background="@drawable/selector_switch_track"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:outlineProvider="background"
        android:thumb="@drawable/selector_switch_thumb"
        app:track="@drawable/selector_switch_track" />
```

*selector_switch_track.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:autoMirrored="true">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/global_white" />
                    <corners android:radius="@dimen/margin_100dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/layer_switch_thumb_map_off" android:gravity="start" android:right="@dimen/margin_56dp" />
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/layer_switch_thumb_list_off" android:gravity="end" android:left="@dimen/margin_56dp" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/global_white" />
                    <corners android:radius="@dimen/margin_100dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/layer_switch_thumb_map_off" android:gravity="start" android:right="@dimen/margin_56dp" />
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/layer_switch_thumb_list_off" android:gravity="end" android:left="@dimen/margin_56dp" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating seperate res dir `drawable-ldrtl` for RTL and put there same `selector` file but with switched start/end drawables.